# Initializing[Unavailable#]-failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed

Tags: session, c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have one class called fixture which has two properties description and date. Now i dont want to operate directly on thi stwo propert but i wanted to operate on Some collection object "Allattribute" in this example which i m feeling while in get and set of each property.

retrival is working fine but while persisting i m getting this error

Initializing[Unavailable#]-failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed.

**Code for Model and Mapper is as below:**

public class Fixture : EntityBase
    {

```
    public Fixture() {
        //PogObject = new List<PogObject>();
        //ObjectFixtureDate = new List<Objectfixturedate>();
    }
        public virtual long IDPOGObject { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry> m_allattributes = new ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry>();
    private IList<FixtureDate> mFixtureDate = new List<FixtureDate>();
    private IList<FixtureDesc> mFixtureDesc = new List<FixtureDesc>();
    private IList<FixtureFlag> mFixtureFlag = new List<FixtureFlag>();


    public virtual IList<FixtureDate> FixtureDate
    {
        get
        {
            mFixtureDate.Clear();
            foreach (var item in m_allattributes)
            {
                if (item.Value is FixtureDate)
                {
                    mFixtureDate.Add((FixtureDate)item.Value);
                }
            }

            return mFixtureDate;
        }


        set
        {
            //try
            //{
                if (value.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in value)
                    {
                        DictionaryEntry dEntry = new DictionaryEntry(item.Dictionary.DictionaryName, item);
                        if (!m_allattributes.Contains(dEntry))
                        {
                            m_allattributes.Add(dEntry);
                        }
                    }
                }
            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{

            //}

            mFixtureDate = value;
        }
    }


    public virtual IList<FixtureDesc> FixtureDescription
    {
        get
        {
            mFixtureDesc.Clear();
            foreach (var item in m_allattributes)
            {
                if (item.Value is FixtureDesc)
                {
                    if (!mFixtureDesc.Contains((FixtureDesc)item.Value))
                    {
                        mFixtureDesc.Add((FixtureDesc)item.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            return mFixtureDesc;
        }


        set
        {
            if (value.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in value)
                {
                    DictionaryEntry dEntry = new DictionaryEntry(item.Dictionary.DictionaryName, item);

                    // DictionaryEntry dEntry = new DictionaryEntry(item.DescNum, item);
                    if (!m_allattributes.Contains(dEntry))
                    {
                        m_allattributes.Add(dEntry);
                    }
                }
            }

            mFixtureDesc = value;

        }
    }




}
```

- **Mapper Class:**

public class FixtureMap : ClassMap {

```
    public FixtureMap() {
        Table("SPOG_ObjectFixture");
        Not.LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.IDPOGObject).GeneratedBy.Foreign("PogObject");
        HasMany(x => x.FixtureDescription).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().Not.LazyLoad().KeyColumn("IDPOGObject").Fetch.Join();
        HasMany(x => x.FixtureDate).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().Not.LazyLoad().KeyColumn("IDPOGObject");

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to persist/save your objects? The error message is pretty clear, you are attempting to save after you have disposed/closed your session. Ensure you keep the session open throughout the entire request and only close/dipose it after all transactions have been commited.

Comment: if instead of customized get and Set method if i put default { get; set; } like this then its not causing any problem. It pops up only when i put some code in my getter setter.